# Using NonlinearModelFit output in multiple Plot instances within DynamicModule

Tags: plotting, fitting, dynamic

I'm creating a script for interactive model fitting where the user selects a 'window' of the data to exclude from the fitting.

I can come up with a MWE like the following:

```
testdata = {{1, 2.9}, {2, 3.2}, {3, 3.2}, {4, 5.1}, {5, 7.1}, {6, 9.1}};
DynamicModule[{data = testdata, fitdata, i1 = {2, 4}},
 Panel[
  Column[{
    IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i1], {1, Length[data], 1}, 
     Enabled -> True], "Min: " Dynamic[i1[[1]]], 
    "  Max: " Dynamic[i1[[2]]]
    ,
    Dynamic[
     Show[
      ListPlot[{data, 
        fitdata = 
         Select[data, First[#] < i1[[1]] || First[#] > i1[[2]] &]}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}],
      Plot[
       Evaluate[
        nlm =  a + b*x + c*x^2  /. 
          NonlinearModelFit[fitdata, a + b*x + c*x^2, {a, b, c}, x][
           "BestFitParameters"]], {x, 1, 6}]
      ]
     ]
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

However, I want to plot the fit curve on top of the data, like above, and then have a separate plot of the residuals and a table of the fit parameters. This is where I run into trouble.

I've tried using `With`, with no luck:

```
testdata = {{1, 2.9}, {2, 3.2}, {3, 3.2}, {4, 5.1}, {5, 7.1}, {6, 9.1}};
DynamicModule[{data = testdata, fitdata, i1 = {2, 4}, nlm},
 Panel[
  Column[{
    IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i1], {1, Length[data], 1}, 
     Enabled -> True], "Min: " Dynamic[i1[[1]]], 
    "  Max: " Dynamic[i1[[2]]]
    ,
    Dynamic[
     With[
      nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
        fitdata = 
         Select[data, First[#] < i1[[1]] || First[#] > i1[[2]] &], 
        a + b*x + c*x^2, {a, b, c}, x]],
     Column[
      Show[
       ListPlot[{data, fitdata}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}],
       Plot[
        Evaluate[ a + b*x + c*x^2  /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]], {x, 
         1, 6}]
       ], 
      ListPlot[nlm["FitResiduals"]]
      ]
     ]
    }]
  ]
 ]
```

Could anyone direct me to how to make `nlm` 'available' to multiple `Plot` instances within `DynamicModule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to arise from syntax errors. In particular:

1. The first argument of `With` must be a list.
2. The second argument of `With` is the expression where your variable `nlm` will be defined, but, you are missing this second element (put your
   column in it).
3. The 1st argument of `Column` needs to be a list

After correcting these issues, it seems to work.

```
testdata = {{1, 2.9}, {2, 3.2}, {3, 3.2}, {4, 5.1}, {5, 7.1}, {6, 
    9.1}};
DynamicModule[{data = testdata, fitdata, i1 = {2, 4}, nlm}, 
  Panel[
    Column[
      {
        IntervalSlider[Dynamic[i1], {1, Length[data], 1}, Enabled -> True],
        "Min: "  Dynamic[i1[[1]]], 
        "  Max: "  Dynamic[i1[[2]]], 
        Dynamic[
          With[
            {
              nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
                fitdata = Select[data, First[#] < i1[[1]] || First[#] > i1[[2]] &], 
                 a + b*x + c*x^2,
                 {a, b, c}, 
                 x]
            }, 
            Column[
              {
                Show[
                  ListPlot[{data, fitdata}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}], 
                  Plot[
                    Evaluate[a + b*x + c*x^2 /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]],
                    {x, 1, 6}]], 
                ListPlot[nlm["FitResiduals"]]
              }
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

[image]